# Perl remove unwanted lines from a String

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perl script. I want to filter out lines that do not match a given regex. The problem is that I can not do that.

I have the following lines:

```
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/SeverityLevelCounter"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FilterSet"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/util/Locale"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/CheckstyleException"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/PackageObjectFactory"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/DefaultContext"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AutomaticBean"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FileSetCheck"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/Filter"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AuditListener"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/lang/StringBuilder"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/lang/Exception"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/io/File"
```

And I want to remove all those that do not start with `com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/` after the `->`

So far my script looks like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -s

use File::Find;

our ($roll);

$dir = shift or die("Folder missing\n");
$prefix = shift;


$command = "javap -v";
$extension = "class";
$temp_file = "temp.tmp";

find(\&wanted, $dir);
sub wanted 
{
    if ($_ =~ /\.$extension$/)
    {
        push (@class_files, $File::Find::name);
    }
}

print "digraph G\n{\n";
    print "node [shape=box]\n";

    foreach $class (@class_files) {
        $class=~ s/(.*)\..*/$1/;
        $_result= `$command $class | grep " = class"`;
        $_result=~ s/.*\/\/ */\"$class\" -> /g;

        $_line.=$_result;
    }

    $_line=~ s/"$dir\//"/g;
    $_line=~ s/\[[A-Z]?//g;
    $_line=~ s/\;//g;
    $_line=~ s/->\s*(.*)/-> \"$1\"/g;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
   perl -ne 'print unless /->\s+"com\/puppycrawl\/tools\/checkstyle"/' filename.txt
```

Comment: something like that but, I'd prefer to have it within the script and not an external command.

Comment: By the way I have tried this on the example I provided, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Tiago, zedoo added one quote too many. The following will work: `perl -ne 'print unless m{->\s+"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle}' filename`

Comment: Now It works, Is there no way of doing this within the script?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your script you can add the following line:

```
$_line = join("\n", grep { $_ !~ m{->\s+"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle} }
                       split(/\n/, $_line) );
```

This (from the back to the front)

a.) splits `$_line` into separate lines

b.) filters out the unwanted lines with `grep`

c.) joins the lines again into $_line

Answer (score 1):

Do this after you create your `@class_spec` list (which you can do with `my @class_spec = split(/\n/, @class_files);`:

```
# only keep the class specifiations that match the desired pattern
@class_spec = grep {
    m# -> com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/#;
} @class_spec;
```

Comment: `@class_files` does not include files that start with the wrong pattern, this information is only obtained after running `$command` in this case `javap -v`

Comment: @Tiago: updated answer - it's much easier to parse the list if you put one class specification per line.

Answer (score 1):

You know that you don't have to use forward slashes for the regex operator. Right?

```
foreach my $line (@list) {
   print "$line" if ($line =~ m(->\s+com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle));
}
```

You can use any character you want after the `m`:

```
foreach my $line (@list) {
   print "$line" if ($line =~ m#->\s+"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle#);
}
```

or

```
foreach my $line (@list) {
   print "$line" unless ($line =~ m@->\s+com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle@);
}
```

etc.

That makes it a lot easier to work with regular expressions that contain slashes.

BTW, you can read in a whole file at once into an array:

```
open (MY_FILE, "file.txt") or die qq(A slow and painful death\n);
my @list = <MY_FILE>;
close (MY_FILE);    #No longer needed. It's in @list.
```

Also, I hate `File::Find` because it breaks every rule in module writing. I wrote my own which doesn't require you to put your whole program in a wanted subroutine or use global variables: http://db.tt/SSAw1x3.

Comment: THis is pretty much my first script. I was attempting to generate a java class callgraph. I did not knew that, thanks it was helpful. I am using `File::Find` to read directories and not files.

Comment: Reading directories. That's what I meant. I was talking about reading the files in directory trees. File::Find does everything a module should not do: Use module variables which makes it impossible to use in threaded applications, and require global variables. Modules are suppose to HIDE complexity. That's why I wrote mine. It's a much cleaner interface.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this could help

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# the desired string
my $to_match = 'com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/';

my $pattern = qr/   # compile the regex
    ->      # start matching from the arrow ->
    \s+     # which is followed by a space
    "       # and then a "
    $to_match   # finally the desired string
    /x; 

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $line =~ /^\s*$/; 
    next unless $line =~ /$pattern/;
    print $line, "\n";
}


__DATA__
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/SeverityLevelCounter"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FilterSet"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/util/Locale"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/CheckstyleException"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/PackageObjectFactory"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/DefaultContext"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AutomaticBean"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FileSetCheck"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/Filter"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AuditListener"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/lang/StringBuilder"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/lang/Exception"
"com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/Checker" -> "java/io/File"
```

Answer (score -1):

Using backticks in a scalar context gives you the program output in a single string, along with the headaches about what characters can match a newline and whether a greedy regex will gobble up multiple lines. Maybe your code would be clearer if you used backticks in a list context:

```
foreach $class (@class_files) {
    $class=~ s/(.*)\..*/$1/;
    my @_result = `$command $class | grep " = class"`;
    s{.*// *}{"$class" -> }g foreach @_result;
    $line .= join'', @_result;
}
```

Comment: That makes your program dependent upon the operating system. Different systems have different types of grep commands, and the whole thing can be done in Perl anyway. Plus, it is now preferred to use qx() instead of backticks.